# Scrolling works only after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scroll

On my first page I have some buttons (promo1, promo2, promo3,...) who respectively lead to the element with the id "promo1" or "promo2" or "promo3",... on the second page.

So when I land to the second page I want to scroll directly to the element I choosed with the button. So I pass the id like that:

```
mysite.com/secondpage/:promo1(/2/3, depends on the button.)
```

and I get the id by using `$routeParams` from `angularJs`.
But I have a really huge problem: the scroll stop on middle of the page (maybe because it stop when the element is viewable on screen, let me know), but if I refresh the page, the scroll do what I ask for and stop on top on the element!

Here is the code I use at the moment:

```
$scope.goToAnchor = function(){
        // This is just one of the test I've made, does not work better.

        // if ($routeParams.anchor == ':promoFamily' || $routeParams.anchor == ':promoGroup' || $routeParams.anchor == ':promoCard'){
        //     $scope.anchor = $routeParams.anchor.replace(':','#');
        //     $('html, body').animate({
        //         scrollTop: $($scope.anchor).offset().top
        //     }, 200);
        // }

        // Code I use:

        if ($routeParams.anchor == ':promoFamily' || $routeParams.anchor == ':promoGroup' || $routeParams.anchor == ':promoCard'){
            $location.hash("#");
            $location.hash($routeParams.anchor.replace(':',''));
            $anchorScroll();
        }
    };
    $scope.goToAnchor();
```

Event if you have only some hints, be free to leave a comment, it will help me as long as i'am working on this for 2 days now...

Comment: Why not use the id of the element in the link? Eg: `mysite.com/secondpage#promo1`. It will automatically scroll to element with id `promo1` without any extra implementation

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin Boss restriction, he want this link. :p (not joking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your elements are not fully loaded when your goToAnchor function is being called.
Use `$timeout` to call `$scope.goToAnchor()` after 1 second(change it according to your page load time).

First, inject `$timeout` in your controller.
Then,

```
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.goToAnchor();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've not tryed this, i will give you my feedback :)

Comment: Works very well, i feel a bit dumb for not trying this, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Inject $timeout in your controller, and use it like below.

```
$timeout(function() {
   $scope.goToAnchor();
});
```

This will help calling the function after rendering the full view.